# Get whole document but File.closeAsync method not working

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an Office 365Addin that gets the entire opened document's data. I'm using [this](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word) as a reference.

When I click the "#submit" button for the first and second time everything works fine, but after that it fails.

From what I read, [Document.getFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/jj715284) only allow 2 documents to be stored in memory. The File.closeAsync closes the document on memory to allow other documents to open, in my case its not instead its returning sliceCount 0 and size 0.

Is there a bug with File.closeAsync or am I missing something from the documentation?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

```
function getDocumentAsCompressed() {
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 /*64 KB*/ }, 
    function (result) {
        if (result.status == "succeeded") {
        // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
        // result.value will return a valid File Object.
        var myFile = result.value;
        var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
        var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
        app.showNotification("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);

        // Get the file slices.
        getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
        }
        else {
        app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
        }
});}



function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
    if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
        if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
            return;
        }

        // Got one slice, store it in a temporary array.
        // (Or you can do something else, such as
        // send it to a third-party server.)
        docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
        if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
           // All slices have been received.
           file.closeAsync();
           onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices);
        }
        else {
            getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
        }
    }
        else {
            gotAllSlices = false;
            file.closeAsync();
            app.showNotification("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
        }
});}


function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
var docdata = [];
for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
    docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
}

var fileContent = new String();
for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
    fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
}}
```

Comment: Hello Oscar.. in what platform are you experiencing this? (windows, online, Mac, iOS)? thanks

Comment: Hi  @JuanBalmori  I'm experiencing this on Word Online.

Comment: thanks I was able to repro this issue. we recently made changes in how Word Online handles this scenario and most probably this is a regression. we are working on a fix now. thanks!

Comment: @JuanBalmori, I appreciate it, thank you for getting back to me so quickly. Please let me know when its working. Thank you again!

Comment: Please try it. It should be working now. Let me know the outcomes

Answer (score 0):

you should try this one . First time when you get the response you have to use **file.closeAsync()** method then it work every time when you need

```
      Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 },
      function (result) {
          if (result.status === "succeeded") {
              const myFile = result.value;
              myFile.getSliceAsync(0, function (result) {

                  let data = result.value.data

                  let btoadata = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data)))
                  let fileobj = {

                      matterNumber: $scope.MatterNumber,
                      fileContent: btoadata
                  }
                  if (btoadata) {

                      myFile.closeAsync()
                  }
                  console.log(fileobj)
                  ProgressLinearInActive();

              });

          } else {
              myFile.closeAsync()

              // Handle the error here
              loadToast("Upload Error");
              ProgressLinearInActive();

          }
      }
  );
```